# Finding an upper bound on the coupon collectors problem

Tags: probability, random-variables, coupon-collector

Suppose I have $n^2\cdot \log^2 n+k$ pairs of boxes (each blue box has a corresponding red box), all independent and each having a coupon from the set $\{ 1,2,...,n\}$ with an equal probability (uniform distribution). By the coupon collector's, I can bound the probability that taking $n\cdot \log n+k$ blue boxes will result in having a coupon of each type.

Among the coupons, there is one type that is considered a winning coupon. To win the game, you need to find a winning coupon from the blue box and a winning coupon from its corresponding red box.

We assume all boxes are numbered, therefore each blue box has a corresponding red box. We also assume that we can distinguish between coupons from blue boxes and those of red boxes. Therefore, the only possibility of winning is having a winning coupon from a blue box and a winning coupon from its corresponding red box.

My idea is taking $n\cdot \log n+k$ blue boxes, knowing we have a winning coupon. Then it has some corresponding red box, might be winning and might not. If we take $n^2\cdot \log ^2n+k$ blue boxes, we will have $n\cdot \log n+k$ red boxes that correspond to a blue box with a winning coupon. And now we use the coupon collector on the set of red boxes...

Now, my question is: how to bound the probability of this procedure to succeed? From what I could tell, the probability is some constant to the $n\cdot \log n+k$ power, which is decreasing for large $n$.

Are there any ways to bound the probability of this procedure to succeed, in a better way? Or will my probability of success always be rapidly $\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Some of what you wrote makes me think the problem is less complex than how you describe it.  At one point you say "the only possibility of winning is having a winning coupon from a blue box and a winning coupon from its corresponding red box."  You have devoted considerable discussion to how many such pairs of boxes there are, and choosing some subsets of blue and red boxes.  You presumably have in mind applying some result about collecting one of each kind of coupon, but this is not well connected to your winning coupon notion.

Comment: Indeed if each  coupon is independent, and the probability a box has a winning coupon is $\frac1n$, and the probability a pair of boxes both have winning coupons is $\frac1{n}^2$, can you say that the probability that $m$ pairs have at least one pair of winning coupons is $1-\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^m \approx 1-e^{-m/n^2}$?

Comment: @Henry putting it this way seems very easy. As it seems from your answer (and from basic logic), the more pairs of boxes I take, the larger my chances are. I'm curious why I got such a different answer. Denote by $p$ the probability of having at least one of each coupon in $n\cdot \log n+k$ blue boxes. So by my way, the probability of getting at least one of each coupon in $n\cdot\log n+k$ sets of size $n\cdot\log n+k$ of blue boxes should be $p^{n\cdot \log n +k}$, right? And then, multiplying by $p$ once more, for the corresponding red boxes. But my expression gets smaller with $n$..

Comment: (I understand demanding to have each type of coupon is stronger, but why my answer gets smaller by $n$, while your answer gets bigger? )